# Does XFCE4 collect any data about users?

Tags: linux, xfce, desktop-environment

Does XFCE4 collect any data and supply developers with statistics? Or is all data private and stored on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the developers of Xfce do not do such thing. However the distros like Ubuntu or Mint does. But always You can turn it totally of.